# Using a result of shell's find as a target in a Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile

Say, there's a source directory with non-defined internal structure, and we want to grab all the files and declare the files they are supposed to be compiled into as targets.

Something like that:

```
SOURCES := $(shell find src -name \*.c)
OBJS := $(addprefix /tmp,$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(notdir $(SOURCES)))))
$(OBJS): $(SOURCES)
    cc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

However, it starts with the second line not working (it's just being empty). So, I ended up replacing it:

```
OBJS := $(shell find src -name \*.c -exec sh -c "basename {} | sed 's/^/\/tmp\/g' | sed 's/\.c/\./o/g'" \;)
```

I don't like this approach much, but otherwise it doesn't seem to be working anyway. Okay, now it's expected to be working. However, the targets don't work as expected, say, as if I declared them explicitly:

```
TARGETS := /tmp/foo.o /tmp/bar.o
$(TARGETS): $(SOURCES)
    ...
```

Instead, I just get an error `No rule to make target /tmp/foo.o`.

So, guess, I have two questions:

1. Why the very first code snippet makes `$(OBJS)` empty?
2. Is there a way to actually implement dynamic targets?

Comment: Use pattern rule, e.g. `%.o: %.c`

Comment: @keltar: +1 on the pattern rule, but you still need a functional `$(OBJS)`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Testing the first snippet on my machine

```
$ uname -a
Linux - 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2 i686 GNU/Linux

$ make -v
GNU Make 3.81

$ cat makefile
SOURCES := $(shell find ./ -name \*.c)
OBJS := $(addprefix /tmp,$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(notdir $(SOURCES)))))
$(info $(OBJS))
```

```
$ mkdir test; touch test/1.c; touch test/2.c; make -f makefile
```

Output:

```
/tmp1.o /tmp2.o
```

The test shows that *the first snippet is ok, except for the missing slash* after `/tmp`.

Questions:

- How do you test the emptiness of `OBJS`?
- Are you sure that `SOURCES` is not empty?
- What is the output of `make` with `$(info $(SOURCES))` in `makefile`?
- Are there any `*.c` files in the `src` directory?

### Testing the second snippet on my machine

```
$ sed --version
GNU sed 4.2.1

$ cat makefile
SOURCES := $(shell find ./ -name \*.c)
OBJS := $(shell find ./ -name \*.c -exec sh -c \
          "basename {} | sed 's/^/\/tmp\/g' | sed 's/\.c/\./o/g'" \;)
$(info $(OBJS))
```

```
$ make -f makefile
```

Output:

```
sed: -e expression #1, symbol 10: unknown modifier for s'
sed: -e expression #1, символ 12: incomplete command s'
sed: -e expression #1, символ 12: incomplete command s'
sed: -e expression #1, символ 10: unknown modifier for s'
```

With that version of the second snippet, `OBJS` is not empty.

Note the removed `'\'` in the first `sed` command and the removed `'/'` in the second command:

```
OBJS := $(shell find ./ -name \*.c -exec sh -c \
          "basename {} | sed 's/^/\/tmp\//g' | sed 's/\.c/\.o/g'" \;)
```

### Is there a way to actually implement dynamic targets?

Yep. It's easy, if you can store .o files in the source directories.

The next snippet does the trick:

```
sources := $(shell find ./ -name \*.c)
objects := $(sources:.c=.o)

$(objects): %.o: %.c
    $(cc) -c $<
```

But perhaps it's not what you want.

With using `VPATH` and a couple of additional strings, you can do better.

```
target   := ./a.out
obj_dir  := ./tmp/
sources  := $(shell find ./ -name \*.c)
objects  := $(addprefix $(obj_dir), $(notdir $(sources:.c=.o)))
dirs     := $(dir $(sources))
VPATH    := $(dirs)

$(target): $(objects)
    $(cc) -o $@ $^

$(objects): $(obj_dir)%.o: %.c
    $(cc) -o $@ -c $<
```

Comment: Can't help it, I have to say it: works like a charm!

Comment: This breaks if the filenames contain a space character :( (that's why I'm here actually, trying to see how people cleanly fix this lol)

Comment: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?712